# Updating values in a dictionary with values from a list

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary and a list as below:

```
api_key_data = {'rpnwky': {'mef11me4wj': 66, 'owputivesc': 0}, 'nlhjqa': {'7ey5cgtm59': 0}}
list_max_quota = [100, 10]
```

I want each list item in `list_max_quota` which is `100` and `10` here to be appended to the values of the inner dictionaries in `api_key_data` and it should look something like:

```
{
'rpnwky': {'mef11me4wj': (66,100), 'owputivesc': (0,100)},
'nlhjqa': {'7ey5cgtm59': (0,10) }
}
```

Can someone please help? I tried it several times in Python3 but unable to crack.

Comment: How is decided whether 100 or 10 is appended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can assume that the dict remembers its insertion order (CPython 3.6+, Python3.7), i.e. that the key `'rpnwky'` precedes the key `'nlhjqa'` when iterating over `data`, you can issue:

```
>>> api_key_data = {'rpnwky': {'mef11me4wj': 66, 'owputivesc': 0}, 'nlhjqa': {'7ey5cgtm59': 0}}
>>> list_max_quota = [100, 10]
>>> 
>>> for (k, inner_dict), quota in zip(api_key_data.items(), list_max_quota):
...     api_key_data[k] = {inner_key: (v, quota) for inner_key, v in inner_dict.items()}
... 
>>> api_key_data
{'rpnwky': {'mef11me4wj': (66, 100), 'owputivesc': (0, 100)}, 'nlhjqa': {'7ey5cgtm59': (0, 10)}}
```

If you cannot rely on the order of `api_key_data`, make `list_max_quota` a dictionary.

```
>>> api_key_data = {'rpnwky': {'mef11me4wj': 66, 'owputivesc': 0}, 'nlhjqa': {'7ey5cgtm59': 0}}
>>> dict_max_quota = {'rpnwky': 100, 'nlhjqa': 10}
>>> 
>>> for k, inner_dict in api_key_data.items():
...     api_key_data[k] = {inner_key: (v, dict_max_quota[k]) for inner_key, v in inner_dict.items()}
... 
>>> api_key_data
{'rpnwky': {'mef11me4wj': (66, 100), 'owputivesc': (0, 100)}, 'nlhjqa': {'7ey5cgtm59': (0, 10)}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate your dictionary and update values.

This assumes your dictionary is *insertion-ordered* as per your definition of `api_key_data`, and should only be assumed in Python 3.7+ (although it is true as an implementation detail in 3.6). Pre-3.6, dictionaries are unordered.

```
api_key_data = {'rpnwky': {'mef11me4wj': 66, 'owputivesc': 0},
                'nlhjqa': {'7ey5cgtm59': 0}}

list_max_quota = ['100', '10']

values = iter(map(int, list_max_quota))

for k, v in api_key_data.items():
    value = next(values)
    for k2, v2 in v.items():
        v[k2] = (v2, value)

print(api_key_data)

{'rpnwky': {'mef11me4wj': (66, 100), 'owputivesc': (0, 100)},
 'nlhjqa': {'7ey5cgtm59': (0, 10)}}
```

Comment: @HemantKumar, Sure. Don't forget to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) (green tick on left) an answer that helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can `zip` the `api_key_data` keys, values, and the `list_max_quota` values together, and then use a list comprehension to format the values how you'd like.

This assumes each `list_max_quota` corresponds with a `api_key_data` by their respective location in the data structures.

```
api_key_data = {'rpnwky': {'mef11me4wj': 66, 'owputivesc': 0}, 'nlhjqa': {'7ey5cgtm59': 0}}
list_max_quota = ['100', '10']

print({key: {k: (v, max_quota) for k, v in value.items()} 
    for key, value, max_quota in zip(api_key_data.keys(), api_key_data.values(), list_max_quota)})
```

Output:

```
{'rpnwky': {'mef11me4wj': (66, '100'), 'owputivesc': (0, '100')}, 'nlhjqa': {'7ey5cgtm59': (0, '10')}}
```